# First Match the string pattern from a row then replace spacific value from just after row in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have below content in my parameter file.

```
[s_m_imgpstna]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT331_DB

[s_m_drcgctln]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_ioxgciln]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_reddecna]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_cd2gcpna]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_cd2gcpna]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_cd2gctna]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_g92gctsp]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_os2gcceu]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_ccpgctdf]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_ew4gciln]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT307_DB

[s_m_dr6gctln]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_dr2gctln] 
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_dr4gctln]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB
```

Now I want to search for the pattern "cd2gcpna" which has two occurrence in file

```
[s_m_cd2gcpna]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB

[s_m_cd2gctna]
$DBConnection1=Insight_QAT291_DB
```

Now I want to replace string which is just below of that(`[s_m_cd2gctna]`) row for all occurrences.

```
$DBConnection1=Insight_**QAT291**_DB
```

replace by

```
$DBConnection1=Insight_**QAT308**_DB
```

Comment: format your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ... and add the code you tried to solve this

Comment: @Amol, please spend your some of the time for re-phrasing your question and use code tags for sample(s) inputs and outputs too.

Comment: @amol, I reformatted your question. Fix it if I broke anything.

Comment: There is no "QAT308" in your sample data.

Comment: Yes QAT291 should be replace by QAT308 in cd2cgpcna

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution:

```
$ awk '/cd2gcpna/{p=1;print;next} \
   p{sub(/291/,"308");p=0}1' file
```

If you want to change your file inplace, with GNU awk you can do this:

```
awk -i inplace '/cd2gcpna/{p=1;print;next} \
   p{sub(/291/,"308");p=0}1' file
```

And with params:

```
$ awk -v pat="cd2gcpna" -v val1=291 -v val2=308 '$0~pat{p=1;print;next} \
    p{sub(val1,val2);p=0}1' file
```

From a shell script:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

pat=$1
val1=$2
val2=$3
file=$4

awk -v pat="$1" -v val1=$2 -v val2=$3 '$0~pat{p=1;print;next} \
    p{sub(val1,val2);p=0}1' $file
```

And call it with:

```
$ ./test.sh cd2gcpna 291 308 file
```

Comment: It is working for me but I want to make it parameterized. I want to pass cd2gcpna and 308 as a argument to script.

Comment: @AmolMurkute see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: @AmolMurkute example with params added.

Comment: Thanks Marc...How I can wrap up AWK in shell script.

Comment: @AmolMurkute Added it to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort @Marc. Really pleased with your help. Again thanks for Stackoverflow team for this wonderful platform.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` method:

```
sed -i '/cd2gcpna/{n;s/QAT291/QAT308/}' file
```

To wrap that in a function, (easier to test than a script, the code's virtually the same either way):

```
# usage: rep_after flagstring fromstring tostring file
rep_after() { sed -i '/'"$1"'/{n;s/'"$2"'/'"$3"'/}' "$4" ; }
```

And call it like so:

```
rep_after  cd2gcpna  QAT291 QAT308  file
```